# CellEditEnded happens too late

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, pagedcollectionview

When the user changes the value of a cell (`DataGridCheckBoxColumn`) and then clicks on another UI element outside of the datagrid, the click event of the other UI element fires before the datagrid  CellEditEnded.

This is a problem because in my case that other UI element is a button that changes Filter property of the PagedCollectionView that is feeding the datagrid (essentially it's simulate a "move to page 2" of rows to edit)  The exception that is thrown is:

'Filter' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.

How do I force the finish of the EditItem (or AddNew for that matter) before setting the filter?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about **silverlight**, but in **WPF** you may try to commit the transaction before setting the filter:

```
if ((collection as IEditableCollectionView).IsAddingNew) (collection as IEditableCollectionView).CommitNew(); // or .CommitEdit();
```